# Obj-C - iPhone 12 - CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called

Tags: ios, objective-c

Super strange - when I tap a map annotation on my app's MapView from an iPhone 12, 12 Pro or 12 Pro Max, I'm thrown the following error in the console:

```
CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
```

Typically, when my annotation is tapped, a view appears over the map. This all works fine on every device accept for when the app is run on either an iPhone 12, 12 Pro & 12 Pro Max.

Any idea how I can fix this, or what it means? Thank you!

Comment: you work on devices right ? Also did you try on another network ?

Comment: Tried on multiple networks, and on multiple iPhone 12s. I'm thrown this error every single time :/ Works just fine on all non-12 devices. @zeytin

Comment: it is not exactly same but i found this thread : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657090

Comment: Thousands of developers are dealing with this. in our case we are trying to figure out if we can release an app when this error was triggered

Comment: @BillAppleton Ugh it's the worst - and it's occurring in random spots for us now rendering the app completely unusable for some users.

Comment: @Brittany i have a support ticket with Apple and I will follow up here on results

Comment: I'm getting this same warning when running altool to notarize a program on MacOS. I cant find an answer for this anywhere.

Comment: Abaga129 is right. I confirm that during notarization of App Bundles with `xcrun atool` this message is printed on MacOS. Probably since I've installed Big Sur. It concerning but according to Apple a not important.